# Does H2SO or H2CO have a higher dipole moment?

Tags: molecular-structure, electronegativity

Given these two molecules, I realize that the molecules are pretty identical in terms of the individual atoms' electronegativities (with Sulfur only being a small bit higher than Carbon). So then, the only factors that I can think of contributing to differences in dipole moment would be shape (tetrahedral vs trigonal planar), the lone pair, and the double bond. However, I don't know how to look at these three factors collectively to determine the net dipole moment.

How would I go about finding which one has a higher dipole moment?

Comment: I suspect H2SO is supposed to be [hydrogen thioperoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_thioperoxide), which molecule isn't tetrahedral and closely resembles the structure of H2O2. Maybe it would be helpful to directly put this structure together with the one for formaldehyde and draw a dipole vector for each.

Comment: Even though H2SO is not really a common chemical usually found in the shelves of labs, the molecule definitely can exist as a stable species as there is nothing wrong with it at all. In fact, just typing "H2SO" into Google instantly gives scientific papers related to it that are published even in high-quality journals. And even if the molecule were not to exist, the question still would make sense as the user is interested in understanding basic concepts, and for this, this way of thinking in chemical analogues is perfect. So I see no reason for cherry-picking here, this is a nice question.

Comment: @andselisk [Or hydrogen sulfoxide?](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hydrogen-sulfoxide-3D-elpot.png)