Does H3PO exist?
If we look at the structures of $\ce{H3PO4},$ $\ce{H3PO3},$ and $\ce{H3PO2}$, it seems entirely possible that a compound with a similar structure with a single oxygen atom can exist. Can anyone please explain?

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00505a002

@Unknown I'm afraid many quite stable phosphine oxide derivatives are known, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphine_oxides https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoryl_chloride https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoryl_fluoride

If you are curious, $\ce{H2SO}$: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/123048/does-sulfoxide-h%e2%82%82so-exist

Note; Please title questions accurately! The answer below is based on the title reading "does it exist?" whereas a responder claims the question was actually about stability.
Phosphine oxide does exist, detected by mass-spectroscopy1 when phosphine is reacted with oxygen and by FT-IR when phosphine is reacted with ozone2. It has also been claimed in some other chemical settings. However, it is not obtainable in condensed form; it is seen only as a gas or in matrix isolation.
References

Hamilton, Peter A.; Murrells, Timothy P. (1985). "Kinetics and mechanism of the reactions of PH3 with O(3P) and N(4S) atoms". J. Chem. Soc., Faraday Trans. 2 (81): 1531–1541. doi:10.1039/F29858101531.

Withnall, Robert; Andrews, Lester (1987). "FTIR spectra of the photolysis products of the phosphine-ozone complex in solid argon". J. Phys. Chem. 91 (4): 784–797. doi:10.1021/j100288a008.



Question is"does H3PO exist?"
